# Karma skips Jasmine some spec files in nested Angular folders

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I have Angular 13 project that was upgraded from Angular 9 or so and am configuring Karma to run specs. For some reason spec files from top folders only are executing, but after a certain depth of folders is reached, specs stop from running.

for example

```
src\app\modules\dialog-manager is a module folder

src\app\modules\dialog-manager\debugging-dialogmgr.spec.ts  - module-folder spec runs

src\app\modules\dialog-manager\dialog-content\debugging-dialogmgr.spec.ts  - this spec does not run  (describe uses different name for spec)
src\app\modules\dialog-manager\dialog-manager\debugging-dialogcnt.spec.ts  - this spec does not run.
```

Module has index.ts to propogate up types from typescript classes. src\app\modules\dialog-manager does have index.ts that contains:

```
export * from './dialog-content';
export * from './dialog-manager';
```

Nothing in index.ts files is spec-related.

If I intentionally make typos in specs in not running spec files I see Karma picking the errors up, so at least compilation is happening.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out to be circular dependency that originally have not been seemingly propagating to Karma web UI but were printing in logs. After partial CD fix I began seeing "loading error" in browser and working through CDs was able to make remaining specs engage.